# Is there a way to ignore `content-type` request header in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am using proxy integration with api-gateway and want the request to passthrough irrespective of what the  `Content-Type` value is passed . In my current implementation if I pass `Content-Type` as `application/pdf` I am getting `415` but I want api-gateway to ignore this content-type header.

Comment: Are you using a proxy or non-proxy integration? Any binary media types defined in API settings? I'm also guessing you have a mapping template defined in your Integration Request.

Comment: @SurajBhatia I am using proxy integration. No binary media type defined and yes I have a mapping tempate with `When there are no templates defined (recommended)` and `Content-Type` as application/json.